# Is there a limit on how many bugs you can hold in Freemarket?

Tags: freemarket

In a recent session I was the superuser, and the very first challenge was a large group challenge, which I lost. As a result I acquired a fistful of bugs. That fistful was enough to dominate many challenges thereafter. Also, just by luck, those challenges did not earn many bugs for the players. If I used all the bugs, the players would not have won any challenge against me for quite some time. Therefore, I held back and didn't use them all. Is there some limit on how many bugs one user or superuser can hold at one time? Should I have just crushed the puny users with the bugs I had rightfully earned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no limit to the amount of bugs any user can hold. Bugs are wiped out at the end of a session so use 'em or lose 'em!